# Prove the multiples of four are a subset of the multiples of 8

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $\{4m | m \in \mathbb{Z} \} \subset \{8n | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

How do I show this? I know that it is true but I don't see a way to prove this.

I know that $8n = 2(4n)$, and $4m = \frac{1}{2} 8m$, but this are just sketches, what is the actual way to prove something like this?

Comment: Apply definition: $A \subseteq B$ **iff** for any $x$, if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$.

Comment: The inclusion should be in the opposite direction, right?

Comment: @Jeong Yeah, exactly my thought.

Comment: Of course, if you can find $z \in B$ such that $z \notin A$, this will prove that $A \nsubseteq B$.

Comment: Thus, try with $4$ ...

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion is the other way around and false as stated. If $A \subseteq B$, then each element of $A$ is also in $B$. In your case, we have to show, that $8n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is in $\{4m : m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. We have $$8n = 4 \cdot(2n) $$ an $2n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $8n \in\{4m : m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ for every integer $n$ and the inclusion is therefore prooven.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.  $12 \in ${$4m | m \in \Bbb Z$} but it is not an element of {$8m | m \in \Bbb Z$}.

The converse is true, proof below:

Let $x \in ${$4m | m \in \Bbb Z$}

Then $x=4m$ for some $m \in \Bbb Z $

Now for $y \in ${$8n | n \in \Bbb Z$} it follows $y = 8n $ for some $n \in \Bbb Z $

But $8n = 4 (2*n) $ where $2*n \in \Bbb Z $ by closure.

Answer (score 0):

Start with listing the elements in each set. $\{4m\mid m\in \Bbb Z\}$ is the set $\{0, \pm 4, \pm 8,\ldots\}$, while $\{8n\mid n \in \Bbb Z\} = \{0, \pm 8,\pm 16,\ldots\}$. Which one looks like a subset of the other?